# PyTorch and GLIBC compatibility error after upgrading JetPack to 4.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pytorch, gnu, glibc

A few days ago we upgraded JetPack to `v4.5` on our Xavier Ubuntu 18.04 aarch64 machine.
After installing PyTorch `v1.7.0` with torchvision `v8.1.0` I receive the following error when running `import torch` in Python `v3.6.9`

```
ImportError: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
```

Currently there is GLIBC `v2.27` installed.

Do you know how can I solve this problem? I read online that upgrading GLIBC is not my best option as this requires a lot of effort and some risk as may other aprty of my system depend on GLIBC `v2.27`.

Comment: Did you find a solution?